# Problem with MPI_Comm_Split and MPI_Bcast

Tags: c, mpi

I created a question a few days ago and thanks to a kind guy I can solve my problem. Now I try to implement a more complex program in C with MPI using MPI_Comm_Split to create a communicator for some groups of processes. I have the process with global rank 0 that isn't in any group, because I want to treat it as if it is a central server, in fact is task is to initialize an array of 4 floating noumbers and send it to the processes that are part of the group 0. This group 0 is made up by 3 processes (process with global rank 1,2 and 3) that I trat they as if they are intermediary server, so they received the array from the central server and forward it to the other groups. I have other 3 groups that contain the rest of the processes (every of this 3 groups has the same numeber of processes).

This is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (size < 7) {
        if (rank == 0) {
            printf("This program requires at least 7 processes.\n");
        }
    } else {
        int group_number;

        if (rank == 0) {
            group_number = -1; // Process with rank 0 does not belong to any group
        } else if (rank >= 1 && rank <= 3) {
            group_number = 0; // New group formed by processes with rank 1, 2, and 3
        } else {
            group_number = (rank - 4) % 3 + 1; // Subdivision of the other processes into 3 groups with numbers 1, 2, and 3
        }

        MPI_Comm comm_group;
        MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, group_number, rank, &comm_group);

        int group_rank;
        int group_size;
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm_group, &group_rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(comm_group, &group_size);

        if (rank == 0) {
            printf("Process %d does not belong to any group because it is the central server.\n", rank);
        } else if(group_number != 0) {
            printf("Process %d in group %d. Rank in the group: %d\n", rank, group_number, group_rank);
        }else{
            printf("Process %d in intermediate server group %d. Rank in the group: %d\n", rank, group_number, group_rank);
        }

        float global_message[4];
        float intermediary_message[4];

        if (rank == 0)
        {
           // Process with global rank 0 initializes the message
            global_message[0] = 10.0;
            global_message[1] = 11.0;
            global_message[2] = 12.0;
            global_message[3] = 13.0;

            printf("Message to send: %f %f %f %f\n\n", global_message[0], global_message[1], global_message[2], global_message[3]);
        }

        // Send message only to processes in group 0
        if (group_number == 0 || rank == 0) {
            MPI_Bcast(&global_message, 4, MPI_FLOAT, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        if (group_number == 0 ) {
            // Print the message received from process 0
            printf("Received message from central server: %f %f %f %f\n\n", global_message[0], global_message[1], global_message[2], global_message[3]);
            
        } 

        if (rank == 1) {
            
            printf("intermediate message 1: %f %f %f %f\n\n", global_message[0], global_message[1], global_message[2], global_message[3]);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                intermediary_message[i] = global_message[i];
            }
        }

        if (rank == 2) {
            
            printf("intermediate message 2: %f %f %f %f\n\n", global_message[0], global_message[1], global_message[2], global_message[3]);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                intermediary_message[i] = global_message[i];
            }
        }

        if (rank == 3) {
            
            printf("intermediate message 3: %f %f %f %f\n\n", global_message[0], global_message[1], global_message[2], global_message[3]);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                intermediary_message[i] = global_message[i];
            }
        }

        if (group_number == 1 || rank == 1)
        {
            MPI_Bcast(&intermediary_message, 4, MPI_FLOAT, 0, comm_group);
        }

         if (group_number == 2 || rank == 2)
        {
            MPI_Bcast(&intermediary_message, 4, MPI_FLOAT, 1, comm_group);
        }

         if (group_number == 3 || rank == 3)
        {
            MPI_Bcast(&intermediary_message, 4, MPI_FLOAT, 2, comm_group);
        }

        if (group_number == 1 || group_number == 2 || group_number == 3 )
        {
            // Print the message received from each process in group 0
            printf("Received the message from the intermediate server: %f %f %f %f\n\n", global_message[0], global_message[1], global_message[2], global_message[3]);
        }

        int group_members[group_size];
        MPI_Gather(&rank, 1, MPI_INT, group_members, 1, MPI_INT, 0, comm_group);

        if (group_number != -1) {
            if (group_rank == 0) {
                printf("Group %d includes the following members: ", group_number);
                for (int i = 0; i < group_size; i++) {
                    printf("%d ", group_members[i]);
                }
                printf("\n\n");
            }
        }

        if (group_number >= 0 && group_number != 0) {
            MPI_Comm_free(&comm_group);
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
mpiexec -np 13 third_example

Process 8 in group 2. Rank in the group: 1
Received the message from the intermediate server: -0.000001 0.000000 -0.000001 0.000000

Process 0 does not belong to any group because it is the central server.
Message to send: 10.000000 11.000000 12.000000 13.000000

Process 1 in intermediate server group 0. Rank in the group: 0
Received message from central server: 10.000000 11.000000 12.000000 13.000000

intermediate message 1: 10.000000 11.000000 12.000000 13.000000

Group 0 includes the following members: 1 2 3

Process 2 in intermediate server group 0. Rank in the group: 1
Received message from central server: 10.000000 11.000000 12.000000 13.000000

intermediate message 2: 10.000000 11.000000 12.000000 13.000000

Process 5 in group 2. Rank in the group: 0
Received the message from the intermediate server: -0.000001 0.000000 -0.000001 0.000000

Group 2 includes the following members: 5 8 11

Process 12 in group 3. Rank in the group: 2
Received the message from the intermediate server: -0.000001 0.000000 -0.000001 0.000000

Process 7 in group 1. Rank in the group: 1
Received the message from the intermediate server: -0.000001 0.000000 -0.000001 0.000000

Process 9 in group 3. Rank in the group: 1
Received the message from the intermediate server: -0.000001 0.000000 -0.000001 0.000000

Process 3 in intermediate server group 0. Rank in the group: 2
Received message from central server: 10.000000 11.000000 12.000000 13.000000

intermediate message 3: 10.000000 11.000000 12.000000 13.000000

Process 6 in group 3. Rank in the group: 0
Received the message from the intermediate server: -0.000001 0.000000 -0.000001 0.000000

Group 3 includes the following members: 6 9 12

Process 11 in group 2. Rank in the group: 2
Received the message from the intermediate server: -0.000001 0.000000 -0.000001 0.000000

Process 4 in group 1. Rank in the group: 0
Received the message from the intermediate server: -0.000001 0.000000 -0.000001 0.000000

Group 1 includes the following members: 4 7 10

Process 10 in group 1. Rank in the group: 2
Received the message from the intermediate server: -0.000001 0.000000 -0.000001 0.000000
```

As you can see, the array forwarding for the group 0 works, but not for the other groups. The comunicator for the processes that I call "intermediary server" and the groups 1,2,3 is the same, but it not works. I think the problem is the fact that the communicator used to forward the array from the central server to the group of intermediate servers is the global one (MPI_COMM_WORLD), but when I try to change it with the group communicator the code don't execute.
Please some one can help me?

Comment: 1 `// Send message only to processes in group 0
        if (group_number == 0 || rank == 0) {` How do you think the other ranks will receive the bcast message if they never call bcast? 2. You have a bunch of bcast calls to the group communicator but they are all inside conditionals. I don't like taht sort of code: it's too easy to miss a case. Do only one bcast call, and use the conditionals to set up the different buffers.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout when you say the other ranks don't call bcast are you referring to the ranks of group 0 or also the ranks of the other groups? I put so many conditions because I'm a beginner in programming with mpi, so I managed to send the messages to all the processes of group 0 I tried to replicate the same logic for the other groups too. So I'm asking a lot, but could you explain a little better what I can do to make the code do what I expect?

Comment: `MPI_Bcast()` occurs within a communicator. So if you want to broadcast from `0` to `[1-3]` (ranks in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`), you must have all these tasks in the **same** communicator.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'm getting very confused. in my idea, the process with rank 0 in MPI_COMM_WORLD must send the message only to all processes that are included in group 0 (i.e. the processes with rank in MPI_COMM_WORLD 1,2,3). In fact, when I write in code
// Send message only to processes in group 0
        if (group_number == 0 || rank == 0) {
            MPI_Bcast(&global_message, 4, MPI_FLOAT, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
do group 0 processes (rank 1,2,3 in MPI_COMM_WORLD) actually receive the message, or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't want to keep bothering you with questions all the time, so, do you happen to know any ways I can learn to program with MPI? (e.g. books, video lessons or links)

Comment: This is not how how collective operations work. `MPI_Bcast() does not send from one "group" to an other "group". But from one rank within the communicator to all the other ranks of the same communicator, so it is up to you to define the communicator accordingly.

Comment: For the sake of completion, you could use an inter-communicator, but let's forget about that for now.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I've done some research, and I've learned that the best solution for what I want to do is to use an intercommunicator, because, having to send a message from a process that belongs to group 0 to a process that belongs to group 1, no there is no other way to do it than using an inter communicator, so I trivially tried to implement some code, but when I run the code something strange happened. I'm using VS code, and the name's teminal powershell changes to mpiexec when I launch the program, and I don't receive any output and the terminal no longer responds to commands.